# Not able to fetch contacts from Salesforce

Tags: python, salesforce

I am trying ti fetch Salesforce contacts. I am using Python for coding. But the error belongs to some kind of permission in enabling in Salesforce . 
I have signed up as developer in salesforce (Selected developer form drop down @ sign up form).

Error I am getting is :

**The REST API is not enabled for this Organization.**

```
Request refused for https://ap2.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id%2C+Name%2C+Email+FROM+Contact. Response content: [{'errorCode': 'API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG', 'message': 'The REST API is not enabled for this Organization.'}]
```

But so far according to m y understanding so far everything is by default enabled for `Developer account` and I am signed up as developer. But still some one have an idea to confirm whether account is developer account or not , let me know. I will confirm that too just to be sure.

Here is my profile, app looks like . 
[image]
[image]

I have selected all permission for my app and here they looks like when authenticating user.

[image]

Comment: try asking this over on http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/ as this is more of a problem of configuration for salesforce and they will know more

Comment: @MikeMcMahon ok. Will do. Is there any way I can like this question there as I can post only once in 40 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Developer Edition? make sure that you checked “API Enabled” permission.

For EE and UE it is automatically enabled.

below are the two links that may help you

https://github.com/heroku/databasedotcom/issues/49

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gnjCAAQ

Comment: Here is my question and answer on `salesforce stack exchamge ` http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145167/not-able-to-fetch-contacts-from-salesforce/145172#145172